# How to obtain .xml/.csv reports from public site report section

Tags: jquery, excel, vba

I am trying to query a public website reporting section, within the reports section are a number of specific reports which follow the example as below;

```
"https:[[web address]/[date][time]"
```

However, before the .xml .csv extension exits, what is usually, a time code of when the report ran, in the format `HHMMSS`.

Can anyone advise on the best method of obtaining these reports?

Have set up other sheets (Google Sheets) which successfully pulls a report when the user enters a specific date. They do not have the report publish time at the end which makes them slightly more simple.

Expected results: user inputs/ selects date, output .csv/.xml file will appear in Excel/Sheets.

EDIT: I have managed to get the above working for .XML files, .CSV is proving more difficult, see below for code which I can get to retrieve results, but not display the info the same as the .XML files.

```
let
dateFrom = DateTime.ToText(Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name = "dateFrom"]}[Content][Column1]{0}, "yyyy-MM-dd"),
dateTo = DateTime.ToText(Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name = "dateTo"]}[Content][Column1]{0}, "yyyy-MM-dd"),
requestParameters = [page="1", sort_by="PublishTime", order_by="DESC", ReportName="ETS Bid File", ResourceName="BidFile_SEM-DA_PWR-MRC-D+1", date_from=dateFrom, date_to=dateTo, page_size="20"],
requestHeaders = [Accept="*/*", Origin="https://www.sem-o.com", Referer="https://www.sem-o.com/market-data/static-reports/index.xml", #"User-Agent"="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.119 Safari/537.36"],
json = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://reports.semopx.com/api/v1/documents/static-reports", [Query=requestParameters, Headers=requestHeaders])),
documentsToRequest = List.Transform(json[items], each [DocumentUri = _[ResourceName]]),
toTable = Table.FromRecords(documentsToRequest, type table [DocumentUri = text]),
csvsOnly = Table.SelectRows(toTable, each Text.EndsWith([DocumentUri], ".csv"))
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: In Excel this should be fairly simple using Power Query. It can load and parse .xml and .csv from a web address and it can be setup with a dynamic URL based on user inputs in the workbook. I don't know Google Sheets, but if you already setup something similar, I would't think adding a formatted time value to the URL would be that much of a problem?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. The main issue is the changing timestamp at the end - is there anyways which can automatically determine what the timestamp will be? If it is not there it wouldn't be the right filepath to follow to obtain the report.

Thanks

Comment: Oh I thought you meant you would be specifying the time as well. In this case I would think you need a way to search for the report of the date you are looking for on the site, so you can tell what the filename is. I would look at how the you normally access these reports on the site, as it is probably possible to replicate this to either return the filename or access the reports directly.

Comment: Thanks for coming back to me on this. Having looked into this more, I think the issue is being caused by the fact that the table is generated "dynamically", I believe by a JS script.

Comment: That sounds annoying. I'm not a web developer of any sort, but I'm fairly certain that would be doable using VBA in Excel, as you can basically run an automated InternetExplorer instance from there that should be able to do anything you normally do in a browser. There's decent resources on how to do this stuff, but it can it be fairly involved. If you could just send a URL based request to the site that returns the report that would be a lot easier, but not sure if that's possible here.

Comment: Given it’s a public service, are you able to supply the domain/url as an example?

Comment: Hi Brad, here are the two URLs which I would be looking to extract reports from:

https://www.semopx.com/market-data/static-reports/ 

https://www.sem-o.com/market-data/static-reports/index.xml 

Thanks
Daniel

Comment: More specifically, if i was looking to pull the report containing Daily exchange rates,  [link](https://www.sem-o.com/market-data/static-reports/index.xml?page=1&sort_by=PublishTime&order_by=DESC&name=exchange&group%5B%5D=Capacity+Qualification&group%5B%5D=Capacity+Auctions&group%5B%5D=Forecast+Data&group%5B%5D=Inputs%2C+Commerical+and+Technical+Offer+Data&group%5B%5D=Registration&group%5B%5D=Settlement+Data&date_from=&date_to=&MARKET=&PUBLICATION=&RUN_TYPE=&PERIOD_TYPE=&page_size=20) note how the end of the report is formatted with date and publish time, e.g. "201901291034.xml".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you still want/need this question answered, given it was asked almost two months ago -- or if you/the user have Power Query for Microsoft Excel.

The approach below currently only works for XML files, as my search criteria/filters were only returning XML files to me. I haven't seen what the CSV files are like in terms of their headers, structure, etc. But adding CSV support shouldn't be too difficult (Power Query can handle CSVs fine).

When you click 'Search' on the page (in a browser), it seems to send a request to a particular URL (with the filter criteria from the page in the query parameters) -- and the server's response contains, among other things, the document names and published times that can be used to request the document(s) you're after. So we can replicate that underlying request.

**Setup/Implementation**

1. Add two named ranges:`dateFrom` and `dateTo` to your Excel file.
2. Add the code below as a new query (I do this in Excel by: `Data > Get Data > From Other Sources > Blank Query > click Advanced Editor in top-left > copy-paste code below > click OK > Click Close & Load`). It should load to the sheet.
3. For convenience, it might be good if you move the named ranges to a few rows above the table (just so that everything can be controlled from one sheet).

---

```
let
    dateFrom = DateTime.ToText(Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name = "dateFrom"]}[Content][Column1]{0}, "yyyy-MM-dd"),
    dateTo = DateTime.ToText(Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name = "dateTo"]}[Content][Column1]{0}, "yyyy-MM-dd"),
    requestParameters = [page="1", sort_by="PublishTime", order_by="DESC", name="exchange rate", date_from=dateFrom, date_to=dateTo, page_size="20"],
    requestHeaders = [Accept="*/*", Origin="https://www.sem-o.com", Referer="https://www.sem-o.com/market-data/static-reports/index.xml", #"User-Agent"="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.119 Safari/537.36"],
    json = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://reports.sem-o.com/api/v1/documents/static-reports", [Query=requestParameters, Headers=requestHeaders])),
    documentsToRequest = List.Transform(json[items], each [DocumentUri = _[ResourceName]]),
    toTable = Table.FromRecords(documentsToRequest, type table [DocumentUri = text]),
    getEachDocument = Table.AddColumn(toTable, "Document", each Xml.Tables(Web.Contents(json[resourceBaseUri] & "/" & [DocumentUri]), null, 65001), type table),
    expand = Table.ExpandTableColumn(getEachDocument, "Document", {"PUB_DailyExchangeRate"}, {"PUB_DailyExchangeRate"}),
    expandNested = Table.ExpandTableColumn(expand, "PUB_DailyExchangeRate", {"Attribute:ROW", "Attribute:TradeDate", "Attribute:FromCurrency", "Attribute:ToCurrency", "Attribute:ExchangeRate"}, {"Attribute:ROW", "Attribute:TradeDate", "Attribute:FromCurrency", "Attribute:ToCurrency", "Attribute:ExchangeRate"}),
    changeTypes = Table.TransformColumnTypes(expandNested,{{"Attribute:ROW", Int64.Type}, {"Attribute:TradeDate", type date}, {"Attribute:FromCurrency", type text}, {"Attribute:ToCurrency", type text}, {"Attribute:ExchangeRate", type number}})
in
    changeTypes
```

The above only needs to be done once.

**Usage**

1. Type/enter valid dates into the named ranges.
2. Refresh the query (I can do this in Excel by right-clicking the loaded table and clicking `Refresh` -- or alternatively `Data > Refresh All`).

Something similar is definitely possible in VBA or Google Apps Script (for Google Sheets), though it makes things easier if the language handles JSON, XML, CSV -- natively or via libraries.

Here's how it looks for me. Named ranges are highlighted, loaded table is below them.

[image: Results]

**Edit: CSV files**:

For CSV files (and CSV files only), something like the following might work. I wrote the below on my phone, so I was not able to test it and the indentation is messy/poor.

```
let
    dateFrom = DateTime.ToText(Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name = "dateFrom"]}[Content][Column1]{0}, "yyyy-MM-dd"),
    dateTo = DateTime.ToText(Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name = "dateTo"]}[Content][Column1]{0}, "yyyy-MM-dd"),
    requestParameters = [page="1", sort_by="PublishTime", order_by="DESC", name="exchange rate", date_from=dateFrom, date_to=dateTo, page_size="20"],
    requestHeaders = [Accept="*/*", Origin="https://www.sem-o.com", Referer="https://www.sem-o.com/market-data/static-reports/index.xml", #"User-Agent"="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.119 Safari/537.36"],
    json = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://reports.sem-o.com/api/v1/documents/static-reports", [Query=requestParameters, Headers=requestHeaders])),
    documentsToRequest = List.Transform(json[items], each [DocumentUri = _[ResourceName]]),
    toTable = Table.FromRecords(documentsToRequest, type table [DocumentUri = text]),
csvsOnly = Table.SelectRows(toTable, each Text.EndsWith([DocumentUri], ".csv")),
    getEachDocument = Table.AddColumn(csvsOnly, "Document", each let csvContents = Csv.Document(Web.Contents(json[resourceBaseUri] & "/" & [DocumentUri]), [Delimiter=",", Encoding=65001]),
promoted = Table.PromoteHeaders(csvContents, [PromoteAllScalars=true])
in promoted)
in
    changeTypes
```

It's definitely possible to have one piece of code that can process both file types (CSV or XML) -- rather than having separate code for CSVs and separate code for XML files. I've not done this above though as I haven't been able to test/seen what the CSVs look like.

Comment: Chillin - Thank you so much for this, have tested this morning and it works like a dream! I appreciate you taking the time to run through this using the links I provided so I can see it in a real working example. 

Have marked your answer as the answer to my question and provided a +1 vote.

Thanks again,
Daniel

Comment: Thanks for your help on this - do you know how to change the code to work with CSV files. I have all XML files working as desired, but cannot get the code above to work for CSV.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @DanielKelso Sorry, I don't have access to a machine right now, posting from my phone. Do you want to try the edit and see if it works/gets you what you need?

Comment: Sorry for the delay in replying - was off on annual leave for a while and only getting back to this now. The above code edit does not seem to work when pointing at CSV files. I have included my code below where I can get it to find a result, but not convert the file in the same way the earlier code did with .XML files. See original post for what I have got so far

Comment: @DanielKelso, could you provide a URL/example for the CSV files? From what I remember, I could only find XML files when I initially answered the question. I will try to take a look tomorrow/next week.

Comment: Here is the link which contains an example CSV File https://www.semopx.com/market-data/static-reports/?page=1&sort_by=PublishTime&order_by=DESC&name=MarketResult_SEM-DA&group=Market+Data&date_from=&date_to=&page_size=20&MARKET=&PUBLICATION=&RUN_TYPE=&PERIOD_TYPE=

There is also another link, which uses drop downs to specify the criteria for the report (Market, date, currency etc), and then a download button to download the data in table format; unsure if this would be easier to use or not.
https://www.semopx.com/market-data/market-results/

Comment: @DanielKelso, have posted a second answer for CSV files. Due to the strange structure of the CSV files, I can't just feed the document to `Csv.Document` function and expand resultant table (as was done for the XML files with `Xml.Tables` function). You will likely need to handle/parse the CSV file in a more specialised manner than what `Csv.Document` allows.

Answer (score 0):

This got me the CSV file for "ETS Bid File" reports for a particular date range.

The problem is that the CSV files don't seem to have a conventional comma-delimited structure. They seem to have multiple "header rows" throughout the file (which indicates that there are effectively multiple CSV files per document).

You will need to explore the remaining transformation for yourself (as you have not specified or shown what you expect the output to be). Due to the unconventional nature of the CSV files, it might be better to use `Lines.FromBinary` or `Text.FromBinary` instead of `Csv.Document` function -- and parse the file in a more custom/specialised manner.

```
let
    dateFrom = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name = "dateFrom"]}[Content][Column1]{0},
    dateFromStringified = DateTime.ToText(dateFrom, "yyyy-MM-dd"),
    dateTo = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name = "dateTo"]}[Content][Column1]{0},
    dateToStringified = DateTime.ToText(dateTo, "yyyy-MM-dd"),
    requestParameters = [
        page = "1",
        sort_by = "PublishTime",
        order_by = "DESC",
        name = "BidFile_SEM-DA_PWR-MRC-D+1",
        group = "Market Data",
        date_from = dateFromStringified,
        date_to = dateToStringified,
        page_size = "20"
    ],
    requestHeaders = [
        Accept = "*/*",
        Origin = "https://www.semopx.com",
        Referer = "https://www.semopx.com/market-data/",
        #"User-Agent" = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.119 Safari/537.36"
    ],
    requestOptions = [
        Query = requestParameters,
        Headers = requestHeaders
    ],
    response = Web.Contents("https://reports.semopx.com/api/v1/documents/static-reports", requestOptions),
    json = Json.Document(response),
    documentsToRequest = List.Transform(json[items], each [DocumentUri = Text.Combine({json[resourceBaseUri], _[ResourceName]}, "/")]),
    toTable = Table.FromRecords(documentsToRequest, type table [DocumentUri = text]),
    csvsOnly = Table.SelectRows(toTable, each Text.EndsWith([DocumentUri], ".csv")),
    FetchCsv = (someUri as text) as table =>
        let
            response = Web.Contents(someUri),
            csv = Csv.Document(response, [Delimiter=",", Encoding=65001, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.Csv])
        in csv,
    invokeFunction = Table.AddColumn(csvsOnly, "Document", each FetchCsv([DocumentUri]), type table)
    // Code to complete transformation should go here. Depends on what you want final output to be.
in
    invokeFunction
```

Comment: Thanks you, again, for your help with this! You've been a great assistance in getting me this far - think I can tweek about with what you have given me to get the desired output.